# bundler not found but gem list shows bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

i use rvm and it works great.

When i type gem list it shows bundler 1.1.5 but which bundler print out: bundler not found.

I did install bundler several times but it doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem with:

```
rvm gemset use global && gem install bundler
```

Apparently there was a problem with the gemset. After using global gemset it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Command for `bundler` gem is not `bundler` but `bundle`. So just type `bundle` on your shell and it will works :)